# Change charter to number using php

Tags: php

I'm New in php My Simply Question I have a String then i want get in number. for example  `a=1,b=2,c=3,` etc... I trying so many times I have Getting only `strlen` string count or length. Please Check My Example

```
    $a = "abc" ;
   echo  $a // output  123
```

Comment: There is no alphabet-position function. You'll have to create something yourself, such as creating an array with position-letter key/values, then figure out the output yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$charmap = array(
    "a" => "1",
    "b" => "2",
    "c" => "3"
);
$string = "abc";

foreach($charmap as $char => $number){
    $string = str_replace($char, $number, $string);
}

echo($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using `array_keys()`

```
$charmap = array(
    "a" => "1",
    "b" => "2",
    "c" => "3"
);
$string = "abc";

$string = str_replace(array_keys($charmap), $charmap, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string="abc";
$list=[
     "a"=>1,
      "b"=>2,
      "c"=>3

  ];


$keys    = array_keys($list);
$values   = array_values($list);
$new_string = str_ireplace($keys, $values, $string);
```